# Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1 in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysql-workbench

When I am trying to insert something to my table I am getting this error on my network tab.
"Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1"

In my database table ID column have the following properties.
id --> int(11), not null, auto-increment.

and I am trying to insert the following details to my table

```
          INSERT INTO `my_table` (`type_id`, `email`, `p_name`, `status`, `call`) 
          VALUES (4, 'name@gmail.com', 'Self', '0', '1')
```

I had also tried passing null to ID while inserting it into the DB table, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely your auto increment column id has grown large and the next auto increment value (which is generated with the insert statement) has become too large for it.
You can confirm this by checking what is the current auto increment value

```
select  `AUTO_INCREMENT`
from  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_SCHEMA = <your db name> 
and   TABLE_NAME   = `my_table`;
```

reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: The AUTO_INCREMENT value can be set no smaller than the highest value the column currently has. Otherwise,the value will be corrected right after the highest column value. Therefore, we may have to update the table to change the highest value in the AI column to a smaller one.

Comment: Thanks, @blabla_bingo running this command helped me. 
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

Comment: The credit goes to DhruvJoshi. Just keep an eye on the highest value the AI column has, as you can not set the  `AUTO_INCREMENT` value higher than that : )